Slash commands say "app didn't responde in time" using discord.py
Am trying to make a bot, I want to add slash commands, but it doesn't work, it always return app didn't respond or didn't respond in time in discord.
This is the code:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime


intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents)


# Fetch the token from environment variables
token = 'token'
# Ensure you set 'DISCORD_TOKEN' in your .env file

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")
    print("Registered commands:")
    for command in bot.tree.get_commands():
        print(f"- {command.name}: {command.description}")
    await bot.tree.sync()
    print("Commands synced.")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    user = str(message.author)
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)

    print(f'Message {user_message} by {user} on {channel}')

    if channel == "test":
        if user_message.lower() == "hi":
            await message.channel.send(f"Hey {user}")
        elif user_message.lower() == "joke":  # Corrected the joke condition
            await message.channel.send("What did the perfume say to the sweat when it defeated it?\nDon't be salty!!")
    await bot.process_commands(message)


def convert_to_unix_timestamp(date_time):
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    timestamp = int(date_obj.timestamp())
    return timestamp


@commands.hybrid_command(name="ping", description="To Test connectivity")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.defer()

    await ctx.send("Pong!")


@bot.hybrid_command(name="time")
async def time(ctx, date, time):
    date_time = f"{date} {time}"
    stamp = convert_to_unix_timestamp(date_time)
    await ctx.send(f"<t:{stamp}:R>")


bot.add_command(ping)


# Use the token variable for running the bot
bot.run(token)


output of using slash command
I expected this to work with no problem, because I did everything I could, I used the app_commands, now using hybrid_commands.
when using the command as a prefixed command it works, but as a slash command it doesn't.

A template for creating Slash commands!!
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    import json
    
    from datetime import datetime
    
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
    
    @bot.tree.command(name="ping", description="To Test connectivity")
    async def add_webhook(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await ctx.send("Pong!")
    
    
    
    bot.run('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN')

